# How can I make a data validation list with easy edition in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation

I would like to make a structure similar with a data validation list in Google Sheet so the others users could contribute to it easily. For example, when I use the sheet I select one data validation structure and there is the following fruits: "banana, apple, orange", I would like to add "grape" at this list , but I would like to do this only by typing grape on the cell, but this would say the enter is invalid. How could I do something like that?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that those fruit selection drop-down lists are in column `F2:F`, use `=F$2:F` as the "List from a range" criteria, and tick the **Show warning** option.

When a new entry is typed in one of the drop-down list cells in column `F2:F`, it gets automatically included as an option in those lists.